# How to add a fixed shopping cart button on the bottom of the page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mobile

How to add a fixed shopping cart button at the bottom of every page, so that it becomes very easy for the mobile users to view the cart. I'm using **woocommerce**.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in footer.php and it worked for me :

```
<div class="buttons" style="margin-top: 12%; float:right; position: relative; ">
<a href="http://sanchibags.com/index.php/cart/" title="Goto Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;"> 
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Goto Cart</a>
```